# Get and set angle/rotation on runtime in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, transformation

I would like to request some help, because I'm getting crazy 
I already have tried the following:

```
var t = (CompositeTransform)var OriginalAngle = t.Rotation;
```

and

```
var _originalAngle = (double)RenderTransform.GetValue(RotateTransform.AngleProperty);
```

But I'm getting exceptions.

I trying to obtain the rotation angle on a constructor, I don't know if make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a name to the RotateTransform.

```
<Rectangle  Name="rectangle1" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" >
        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform x:Name="myAngle" Angle="90" />
        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
</Rectangle>
```

Then to access it through code just use myAngle.Angle

Comment: Hi danbord, I didn't use your solution, but you help me to see the solution. I didn't have 'RotateTransform' on my XAML, but instead I have 'CompositeTransform' and this was causing the error.